# Weird CSS element size issue

Tags: html, css

I am generating html dynamically from js, have a container and I'm adding new elements to it where each element has an image inside which will give the element's size eventually.

**The problem I have is that the container does not grow in size after the elements have been added.** I understand that images load slower but once loaded I would expect it would recalculate the space occupied and update the container.

In the code, the container's width is 500px, whereas `.scroller` and `.row` should be much wider but they are the same.

I would expect that .row would grow and with it .scroller as well but they stay at the same width.

https://jsfiddle.net/slash197/b8mb9ud9/6/

```css
.hot-zone {
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hot-zone .scroller {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.hot-zone .scroller .row {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hot-zone .scroller .row .item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.hot-zone .scroller .row .item img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hot-zone">
  <div class="scroller">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/439212e4-5ef7-41cd-8878-af96d485a512_hm0Z5tpRlSzPO97U5e2Q32Y0Xrb.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/e68ce54f-79d8-4d43-b98f-73b7d5271745_5z4Bj0zUupF7z4VW0REAdso1uxz.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/66df333e-d08f-48a1-b8c1-0ebce14ccc7e_5gJkVIVU7FDp7AfRAbPSvvdbre2.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/322ec0fa-3687-4a49-b070-c3b9188d916b_i0t7F6b4R1wURRESAiw9VJNuVoV.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/7e7a82e6-0f11-48bb-bed3-48bfaf3b374c_iMkl2Akc1f4CSJCieVwczM4KjZR.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/bedbd348-53c3-4765-9c8d-dc462ed7ecf9_gri0DDxsERr6B2sOR1fGLxLpSLx.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/c876d47d-f511-4402-9980-5bfc122965c5_tIKFBxBZhSXpIITiiB5Ws8VGXjt.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/439212e4-5ef7-41cd-8878-af96d485a512_hm0Z5tpRlSzPO97U5e2Q32Y0Xrb.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/e68ce54f-79d8-4d43-b98f-73b7d5271745_5z4Bj0zUupF7z4VW0REAdso1uxz.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/66df333e-d08f-48a1-b8c1-0ebce14ccc7e_5gJkVIVU7FDp7AfRAbPSvvdbre2.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/322ec0fa-3687-4a49-b070-c3b9188d916b_i0t7F6b4R1wURRESAiw9VJNuVoV.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/7e7a82e6-0f11-48bb-bed3-48bfaf3b374c_iMkl2Akc1f4CSJCieVwczM4KjZR.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/bedbd348-53c3-4765-9c8d-dc462ed7ecf9_gri0DDxsERr6B2sOR1fGLxLpSLx.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="//cloudtv.akamaized.net/test_client/images/Dutch/c876d47d-f511-4402-9980-5bfc122965c5_tIKFBxBZhSXpIITiiB5Ws8VGXjt.jpg" style="height: 150px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In my browser .row grows horizontally and I get a horizontal scrollbar to see all pictures.
I wonder if it's your browser's issue or we just don't understand the problem well enough. Otherwise @VladimirRadan's answer is correct.

Comment: Not exactly clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: messed up the fiddle, it's updated

Comment: It is still not clear...

Comment: `.row` is 500px instead of 1400px, I can't explain it any simpler

Comment: .row can only extend up to 500px because its parents are limiting the overflow to hidden. Hope this helps.

Comment: @IzzyCooper overflow hides the content but it does not limit the size of child elements

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding what the problem is here.

Comment: If the problem is that .row is not expanding in width as more content is added, then the culprit is the overflow value set on .hot-zone. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Comment: @IzzyCooper overflow changes the visibility of content, it does not affect size, try it and see for yourself before quoting the definition, I know very well what it does but it seems you do not

Comment: I have done my part. Hope you figure this out. Good luck.

Comment: Please update the snippet with the code that adds more content in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

**Change**

```
.hot-zone {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**to**

```
.hot-zone {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Your parent `overflow : hidden` property hide all the child content inside that.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, to hide the overflow. All this does it adds scrollbars so I can scroll it but that's not what I want. And the row size is still the same, actually smaller because of the scrollbar

Comment: So what will happen to the extra images. Are they going to break into the second row?. I'm not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your jsfiddle and when I removed fixed width from .hot-zone container the other two class grew together with parent. Your expectations are correct the container should grow. Also I would suggest to look at flexbox and replace your implementation with flexbox. Flexbox will give you control on how flex-items will behave/grow etc.